# Is this formal enough? "Should I expect to get a call from you sometime this week?"

Tags: phrases, american-english

I'm contacting HR person from a company after an interview.

She told me she will contact me right after the interview, but she sent me an e-mail she will contact me at a later time.

So I'm trying to send an e-mail to ask when to expect a call.

Is the sentence:

> Should I expect to receive/get a call from you sometime this week? I would greatly appreciate if you could let me know.

formal enough or should I write something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement of "Should I expect to receive a call from you sometime this week?" is fine; here are a couple alternatives in case you like one of them any better:

> Can we arrange a specific time for the call?
>
> Can you provide me with the approximate time to expect your call?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with "Should I expect a call this week?" or "When should I expect a call?" Though if there is a degree on my wall, I haven't seen it.